# Regex matching word atleast one character

Tags: regex

I want to match string which contain words with/without spaces but it should contain at least one non blank space character.  Is this below regex correct?

```
/[\w]*[\s]+/
```

Comment: One non blank space character?  Can you give examples of what should match, and what shouldn't?  Should anything besides spaces and word characters be matched?  Like, should it fail if punctuation is present?  Clarify and I'll remove the -1.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to match string that has to include something, the best way is to put a positive lookahead at the begining of the capture, so if you want to ensure there will be some white-space character, then you should start with regex pattern `((?=.*\s)...)`, where `...` is rest of pattern. If you mean space-bar character only (because `\s` will match also tab-char `\t` and new line characters `\n` and `\r`), then start with `((?=.* )...)`.

Now - what you mean by word? You used `\w` - which is shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If that is what you want, then your regex pattern is `((?=.*\s)[\w\s]*)`, resp. `((?=.* )[\w ]*)`.

But that would match also string with one white-space character, resp. space-bar character only, nothing more. You should clarify your question, as I believe you want something else, not this....

Answer (score 0):

should match,

stackoverflow  #2    -> should match any characters including special characters

stackoverflow 2   -> should match even if starts with a blank space

should not match,

```
                -> containing only blank spaces
```